# What's the capital A on the right of the input box?

Tags: starcraft-2

[image: screen capture of it]

This thing. I have no clue what it is.

Comment: That's funny, never seen it before myself :S

Comment: I don't play Starcraft, so I can't say for sure, but two guesses: 1) A GUI button to submit typed text (instead of hitting Enter), 2) A button that allows you to change your font styling (bold, italic, underline, colour, etc)

Comment: Have you tried clicking on it?

Comment: It can't be clicked on and it doesn't have a tooltip like a clickable button would. It also doesn't change with Caps Lock or Num Lock. Hrm...

Comment: I had to test it out, I added a friend to a party and the icon doesn't show up for me. Any other tips on reproducing this?

Comment: @Sorean I can reproduce it in any textbox, starting with the login screen. The text field in the friends list (the "Broadcast to friends" or whatever it's called) shows it, too.

Comment: That's really weird Anna, I don't see it in my game. Is your "command hotkey text" option enabled?

Comment: It might only exist, if you have more than one language option installed on your OS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It shows the configuration of your keyboard, allowing to change between alphabets, for example from latin to cyrillic or korean.

It is used for players discussing in different languages and needing different keyboard configurations.

EDIT: So I tested a bit around.

I installed the russian and english keyboard layouts on my Windows system and checked that I could switch from my french layout "FR" to russian "RU" or english "EN" by pressing ALT+SHIFT.

I then launched Starcraft 2. I can confirm that the "A" means latin characters and RU means cyrillic characters. English and French layouts both show an 'A' because both use the latin alphabet.

[image: Testing keyboard layouts]

Answer (score 14):

This sign indicates selected language. For me there are 'En' and 'Ru' states of this icon.

Comment: I demand Canadian spellings in my English game!

Comment: Any idea what languages are available?

Comment: What does A stand for, anyway? I haven't found anything in the ISO-639, which are either two-letter or three-letter codes.

Comment: It's not the language, it's the keyboard layout.

Comment: Interesting theory, but why A and not the actual name or a shortened version?